# "You're not on Teams yet, but you can set it up for your organization." when logging in with private account on PC (Browser and App)

Tags: microsoft-teams

How can I start the Microsoft Teams App on a private computer with my private Microsoft Account without getting the final message "You're not on Teams yet, but you can set it up for your organization." which does not lead anywhere?

There are numerous support tickers which didn't help me further on the following webpages:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/
https://support.microsoft.com/

I need to get this working soon, so any help is appreciated. On my phone the app seems to work, at least I can log-in without any problem.

---

**Additional note on what I've tried:**

When I try and sign up [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/free) with "Sign up for free" I'm forwarded to the following HTTP-Response:

```
Access to businessstore.microsoft.com was denied
You don't have authorization to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403
```

Next, when I click on "Already using teams? Sign in now!", then choose my account "andreas.luckert@outlook.com", login, I get to the page where to choose between "Get the linux app" and "Use web app instead".
Following, I click on "Use web app instead" to be forwarded to the aforementioned final page where I can't seem to get any further saying

> You're not on Teams yet, but you can set it up for your organization.

[image]

This is the exact same thing I get when I choose the other option "Get linux app", install it and log in there.
Actually, from there the circle closes, because when I click on "Sign up for teams" it forwards me to [the exact same page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/free) from where I began the odyssey.

---

**System specifics:**

- Lubuntu 20.04 LTS
- Google Chrome (Teams in browser)
- [Microsoft Teams App for Ubuntu Linux](https://www.microsoft.com/en/microsoft-teams/download-app#desktopAppDownloadregion)

Comment: Which login are you using for Teams? Did you [signup here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/free)?

Comment: See my additional note. These issues are happening on my computer with Google Chrome. On my Android phone though, I've installed the app and logged in successfully.

Comment: Strange, when I click on "Sign up for free" I get into the "Enter an email" [page](https://signup.microsoft.com/create-account/signup?products=CFQ7TTC0K8P5:0004&culture=en-us&country=US&lm=deeplink&lmsrc=FreePageWeb&cmpid=FreemiumSignUpHero&ali=1). Try perhaps to use directly this link.

Comment: Alright, this worked, thanks! As I'm going to use this mainly professionally, I selected the professional use case, but then I had to type a specific company. I invented "Company" as the name for it to be able to proceed. Afterwards I realized that Teams now treats me as a kind of company owner who organizes team meetings with Teams. Well, I don't mind as long as I can join Team Meetings I'm invited to from any company or person in the world, is that correct?

Comment: I added an answer for other users. As to your question: A business user can do anything that a client can, and more. Some options may be payable, but I never used such an account.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've just accepted and upvoted your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some unknown reason, the poster wasn't getting to the Sign-on screen when using
the "Sign up for free" button. This perhaps had something to do with his Linux
or browser version which caused the Microsoft site to malfunction.

The solution was to use directly the
[URL for Sign-up](https://signup.microsoft.com/create-account/signup?products=CFQ7TTC0K8P5:0004&culture=en-us&country=US&lm=deeplink&lmsrc=FreePageWeb&cmpid=FreemiumSignUpHero&ali=1).